# ¿Quiero hacer una consulta usando ajax en php,para que me muestre los datos según su categoría, pero solo traiga los datos dando click en un boton?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Hago una consulta y paso el parámetro, según la categoría me liste los productos, 
`$GLOBALS["lista"]= $GLOBALS["productos"]->listaProductos("DOTACION");`

La cual si le doy click en un botón, me traiga estos datos.

```
if(isset($_GET["dota-test"])){
    function lista(){
    $GLOBALS["lista"]= $GLOBALS["productos"]->listaProductos("DOTACION");
    echo 'si';
    }

    lista();
}
```

La tabla, esta oculta al darle click al botón, quiero que la tabla aparezca y mediante un `ajax`, llene la tabla.

```
$(function() {
              $(document).on('submit','#form-test',function(event) {
                  event.preventDefault();

                    $.ajax({
                      type: 'GET',
                      url: "../Controller/listaProductos.php",
                      data: $(this).serialize(),
                      success:function(response) {
                       console.log(response);
                       if(response=='si'){
                           $("#tabla1").show(1000);
                           $("#producto").show(2000);
                       }
                    }   
                  });


            });
        });
```

En consola, me aparece los datos, pero en la pagina aparece la tabla vacía, ya intente de todo, entonces por favor si alguien sabe del tema me puede ayudar.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

veo que estas mostrando la tabla cuando te llega el resultado desde tu llamado `AJAX` pero no estas llenando tu tabla con los datos obtenidos, para hacerlo puedes revisar el codigo que te dejo en este [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hpxyssou/2/)

Cualquier duda quedo a la orden.

Comment: Pero es que en la tabla tengo una modal, para editar el total, y ademas si selecciona otra categoría quiero que oculte unas columnas.

Comment: Ok, pero esa son otras cuestiones, al punto que fui yo fue justamente al cual preguntaste, para esas otras 'caracteristicas' de tu tabla vas a tener que buscar el como hacerlas al igual como lo hiciste con esta pregunta.

Comment: Pues es que esas funciones ya las hice, la de ocultar las columnas y llenar la tabla, pero llene la tabla con datos directos de php, osea select* from productos, pero ahora quiero es mostrar esos datos dependiendo de donde de click el cliente.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la solución a mi problema.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Este es el código:

```
      $(function() {
          $(document).on('submit','#form-test',function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: "../Controller/listaProductos.php",
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data: $(this).serialize(),
                  success:function(response) {
                   //console.log(response);

                   for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
                   $("#producto").append('<tr>' +
                    '<td>' +response[i]['descripcion'] + '<td>'+
                    '<td align="center"  >' +response[i]['tipo'] + '<td>'+
                    '<td align="center" class="genero" >' +response[i]['genero'] + '<td>'+ 
                    '<td align="center" class="talla" >' +response[i]['TALLA'] + '<td>'+
                    '<td align="center" class="cargo" >' +response[i]['cargo'] + '<td>'+
                    '<td align="center"  >' +response[i]['totalUsado'] + '<td>'+
                    '<td align="center"  >' +response[i]['totalNuevo'] + '<td>'+
                    '<td align="center" >' + '<a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-book-id="'+response[i]['idProducto']+'" >'+'Edita'+'</a>'+  '<td>'+
                    '<tr>');
                    }
                    if(response[0]['categoria']=='SEGURIDAD'){

                      $("#genero").hide(1000);
                      $("#talla").hide(1000);
                      $("#cargo").hide(1000);
                      $(".genero").hide(1000);
                      $(".talla").hide(1000);
                      $(".cargo").hide(1000);
                   }
                   if(response[0]['categoria']=='DOTACION'){

                      $("#genero").show(1000);
                      $("#talla").show(1000);
                      $("#cargo").show(1000);
                      $(".genero").show(1000);
                      $(".talla").show(1000);
                      $(".cargo").show(1000);
                   }
                   $("#tabla1").show(1000);
                }   
              });


        });
    });
```

Comment: Que bueno que hayas encontrado la solución. Por favor recuerda [aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.